# How use Plastic SCM path selector in Teamcity plugin

Tags: teamcity, plasticscm

I have in main branche two folders Apps and Assets and in Teamcity configuration selector is:

```
repository "Repo@127.0.0.7:8887"
path "/Apps"
branch "/main"
checkout "/main"
```

Why not acceptable path "/Apps" command? Still me downloaded all files in work direcotry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the TeamCity **VCS checkout rules**:

VCS Checkout Rules allow you to check out a part of the VCS root configured and to map directories from the version control to subdirectories in the build checkout directory on a Build Agent. Thus, you can define a VCS root for the entire repository and make each build configuration checkout only the relevant part of it.

You cannot configure this behavior editing the selector. You can direclty copy the selector from the Plastic SCM GUI --> "Items" view --> right-click --> set selector.

Comment: Please check "View/Edit selector" at https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gui/plastic-scm-version-control-gui-guide.shtml#CommandsintheRepositoryBrowserView

Comment: Sorry I not have any "Repository browser"... v5.4.16.781

Comment: You can do it from the "Items" view as well. You can reach us at support at codicesoftware dot com if you still face any issue.